# How can I get the value at the end of a string?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple and quick text-based java dungeon crawler.

The player can type in simple 3 letter commands followed by a number value like this:

> NTH 21, or ATT 3, or CST 102, etc...

I know how to get the first 3 letter command using `substring()`.

I also know I can use `substring()` to get the end of a string like this:

```
amount = gameInput.substring(gameInput.length() - 3)
```

But I'm not sure how to handle it since the amount can be any size of number like 1, or 28, 490, 4329, etc...

Here is what I have so far:

```
// example move commands 'NTH 10', 'EST 3', 'WST 320', 'STH 11'
// example combat commands 'ATT 333', 'CST 7102', 'STH 4'

system.out.print("Enter your character action and value amount: ");
system.out.print("\n ** Enter 'END 9' to end game **");

while(userInput != "END 9")
{ 
    gameInput = myScanner.nextLine();

    // character action
    direction = gameInput.substring(0, 2);
    
    // action amount
    amount = 

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can split over space if the command is always two words with the second being the number, or you can use regular expressions to match a number in the command

Comment: Why is `S` in system not capital here: `system.out.print("Enter your character action and value amount: ");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use String#split like:

```
String[] args = userInput.split(" ");
```

it will split the string by space.

then to get the last argument use:

```
String lastArg = args[args.length - 1];
```

I hope I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Given your described input format, it should be as easy as :

```
gameInput.split(" ")[1]
```

The `split` method will split the string into an array of tokens separated by space. The second one should correspond to your number.

Comment: Oh I see, so `substring()` won't work at all?  Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell: you can make this work with `substring()` as well, but it's way more cumbersome. You'll have to basically figure out the length which is more work than just using `split()` (or something using regex).

Comment: You can technically make it work with substring() using String.indexOf(), but the split solution is better.

Comment: So for the line, `gameInput.split(" ")[1]`, it splits it at the space like you said, and 0 is the command and 1 is the value?  so the line for both would be like `direction = gameInput.split(" ")[0];` and `amount = gameInput.split(" ")[1]` ?

Comment: @JoachimSauer if the Strings are in a fixed format as the question implies one would not need to figure out the length and could just use `string.subString(string.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);` to get a substring of the end of the String starting from the last (excluded) space.

Comment: Or if the first command is always 3 letters followed by a space then `amount = gameInput.substring(4);` would also work. Whether that is better and or less error prone than splitting is of course another question., but it would certainly work without having to know anything about the actual length of the number at the end.

Answer (score 1):

One practice is to use String `split` method

```html
public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String first = "EAS 1427";
        String second = "CST 2";
        System.out.println(extract(first));
    }

    public static String extract(String input){
        String [] value = input.split(" ");
        return value[1];
    }
}
```